visualforce test class ApexPages List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Despite having all records properly created, this test class is still throwing an error "List has no rows for assignment to SObject" in the line
UpdateRecordWithLocationController controller = new UpdateRecordWithLocationController(stdController);

(I built a VF page to gather the user's GPS location and save it into a Visit record.)
Here is the test class:
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class UpdateRecordWithLocationControllerTest {
    
    static testMethod void testUpdateRecordWithLocation() {
        Decimal nuevaLatitud = 37.7749; // Example latitude
        Decimal nuevaLongitud = -122.4194; // Example longitude
        String recordId;
        String idVisita;
        // Create test data
        Account acc = new Account(
            Name='Test'
        );
        insert acc;
        RetailStore retailStoreRecord = new RetailStore(
            AccountId = acc.id,
            Name='Test',
            Latitude = 37.7749, // Example latitude
            Longitude = -122.4194 // Example longitude
        );
        insert retailStoreRecord;
        
        Visit visitRecord = new Visit(
            PlaceId = retailStoreRecord.id,
            Origen_vista__c = 'Presencial',
            Direcci_n_de_la_visita__Latitude__s = 37.7749, // Example latitude
            Direcci_n_de_la_visita__Longitude__s = -122.4194, // Example longitude
            BC_Mensaje__c = 'Test Message',
            PlannedVisitStartTime = system.now(),
            Status = 'Planned'
        );
        insert visitRecord;
        recordId=visitRecord.Id;
        idVisita=recordId;
        
        system.debug('acc: '+acc);
        system.debug('retailStoreRecord: '+retailStoreRecord);
        system.debug('visitRecord: '+visitRecord);

        // Set up controller with StandardController and page parameters
        ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(visitRecord);
        UpdateRecordWithLocationController controller = new UpdateRecordWithLocationController(stdController);
        controller.recordId = visitRecord.Id;
        controller.latitude = 123.456;
        controller.longitude = 789.012;
        
        // Test the updateRecordWithLocation method
        Test.startTest();
        PageReference pageRef = controller.updateRecordWithLocation();
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Add assertions based on expected behavior after method execution
        // For example:
        System.assertEquals('/'+visitRecord.Id, pageRef.getUrl());
        // Add more assertions as needed
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testTerminarVisita() {
        // Create test data
        Visit visitRecord = new Visit(
            // Populate necessary fields
        );
        insert visitRecord;
        
        // Set up controller with StandardController and page parameters
        ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(visitRecord);
        UpdateRecordWithLocationController controller = new UpdateRecordWithLocationController(stdController);
        controller.recordId = visitRecord.Id;
        
        // Test the terminarVisita method
        Test.startTest();
        PageReference pageRef = controller.terminarVisita();
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Add assertions based on expected behavior after method execution
        // For example:
        System.assertEquals('/'+visitRecord.Id, pageRef.getUrl());
        // Add more assertions as needed
    }
        
}

And here's the Apex class:
public class UpdateRecordWithLocationController {
    public String recordId { get; set; }
    public String idVisita { get; set; }
    public Decimal latitude { get; set; }
    public Decimal longitude { get; set; }
    public Boolean botonIniciar { get; set; }
    public Boolean botonTerminar { get; set; }
    public UpdateRecordWithLocationController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        idVisita = recordId; //una curiosidad de falla 
        Visit obj = [SELECT Id, Origen_vista__c, Direcci_n_de_la_visita__Latitude__s, Direcci_n_de_la_visita__Longitude__s, BC_Mensaje__c, status FROM Visit WHERE Id = :idVisita LIMIT 1];
        switch on obj.Status{
            when 'Planned'{
                botonIniciar=true;
                botonTerminar=false;
            }
            when 'InProgress'{
                botonIniciar=false;
                botonTerminar=true;
            }
            when else{
                botonIniciar=false;
                botonTerminar=false;
            }
        }
        if(obj.Direcci_n_de_la_visita__Latitude__s==null || obj.Direcci_n_de_la_visita__Longitude__s==null) {
            botonIniciar=false;
            botonTerminar=false;
        }
    }
    public PageReference updateRecordWithLocation() {
        //Alerta, se hizo este cambio por un fallo de lógica no encontrado
        //Las variables se corrigen así
        Decimal nuevaLatitud = decimal.valueof(recordId);
        Decimal nuevaLongitud = latitude;
        Visit estaVisita = [select id, ActualVisitStartTime, placeId, Origen_vista__c, BC_Mensaje__c from Visit where id =: idVisita LIMIT 1];
        RetailStore estaTienda = [select id, Latitude, Longitude from RetailStore where id =: estaVisita.PlaceId LIMIT 1];
        Boolean esLlamada = false;
        if(estaVisita.Origen_vista__c == 'Llamada' || estaVisita.Origen_vista__c == 'Extra ruta llamada' ) {
            esLlamada=true;
        }
        Location ubicacionTienda = Location.newInstance(estaTienda.Latitude,estaTienda.Longitude);
        Location ubicacionVendedor = Location.newInstance(nuevaLatitud,nuevaLongitud);
        Double distancia = Location.getDistance(ubicacionTienda, ubicacionVendedor, 'km');
        try {
            estaVisita.cgcloud__Geolocation__Latitude__s = nuevaLatitud;
            estaVisita.cgcloud__Geolocation__Longitude__s = nuevaLongitud;
            estaVisita.ActualVisitStartTime = system.now();
            estaVisita.BC_Mensaje__c = 'Visita iniciada';
            estaVisita.Status='InProgress';
            estaVisita.BC_Mensaje__c='';
            update estaVisita;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error al actualizar: ' + e.getMessage()));
        }
        return new PageReference('/'+this.idVisita);
    }
    public PageReference terminarVisita() {
        try{
            Visit obj = [SELECT Id, ActualVisitEndTime, cgcloud__Geolocation__Latitude__s, cgcloud__Geolocation__Longitude__s, BC_Mensaje__c, Status FROM Visit WHERE Id = :idVisita LIMIT 1];
            obj.Status='Completed';
            obj.ActualVisitEndTime = system.now();
            obj.BC_Mensaje__c='';
            update obj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error al actualizar: ' + e.getMessage()));
        }
        return new PageReference('/'+this.idVisita);
    }
}

Just in case, I'm also adding the VF page:
<apex:page standardController="Visit" extensions="UpdateRecordWithLocationController" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <body onload="buscaUbicacion(); return false;">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:commandButton value="Iniciar visita" onclick="getLocationAndUpdateRecord(); return false;" rendered="{!botonIniciar}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Terminar visita" action="{!terminarVisita}" rendered="{!botonTerminar}" />
            <apex:actionFunction name="updateRecordWithLocationAction" action="{!updateRecordWithLocation}" rerender="messages">
                <apex:param name="recordIdParam" assignTo="{!recordId}" value=""/>
                <apex:param name="latitudeParam" assignTo="{!latitude}" value=""/>
                <apex:param name="longitudeParam" assignTo="{!longitude}" value=""/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <apex:outputText >&nbsp;{!llamaAlerta}</apex:outputText>
        </apex:form>
    
        <script>
            function getLocationAndUpdateRecord() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        function(position) {
                            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                            updateRecordWithLocationAction(latitude, longitude);
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            alert("Error getting location: " + error.message);
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</apex:page>

Edit:
I checked the record creation at the beginning of the test class, and all three records (account, retailstore and visit) are properly created.
I don't know what else to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Best

In the page constructor you are getting the Id via the querystring parameter so you need to set for the test class to query properly.
PageReference myVfPage = Page.YOUR_PAGE_NAME;
Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', vistaRecord.Id);


Thank you! It did the magic.

You're not using the standard controller, but instead a page parameter.
There are two fixes to this (use only one).
The first option is to use the stdController in your constructor.
public UpdateRecordWithLocationController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    Visit obj = (Visit)stdController.getRecord();
    // Unclear if you need both
    recordId = idVisita = obj.Id; //una curiosidad de falla 
    // rest of code...

The second option is to set the page parameter:
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', visitRecord.Id);
UpdateRecordWithLocationController controller = new UpdateRecordWithLocationController(stdController);

